# How change position just of a chapter

Tags: titles

It only has to affect the first chapter, the others have to remain intact, I have this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
 \begin{document}
\chapter*{ETAPA}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION


\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```

i need this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to do this for just one unnumbered chapter and not for all of them. Anyway, here it is.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{showframe} % for showing text block borders

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\differentchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50}{20}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{40}{70}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\bfseries}{\centering\bfseries}{}{}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\differentchapter{ETAPA}

this intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION

\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the content also should change of position

Comment: @x-rw Did you tell so? Remove the second `\patchcmd` line.

Comment: the margin right, left and bottom  
they should not be modified

Comment: @x-rw Are they? I don't think so. I added `showframe` just to show them, remove it in the final version.